# How to get user's tweets with scribe?

Tags: java, twitter, scribe

Hi i'm still pretty new to Scribe. I understand from the following that it is making a request to post a status.

```
private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json";
```

This is the post URL and this is how the request is made.

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
        request.addBodyParameter("status", textArea1.getText());
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();
```

i understand if i want to get the user's tweets i would need the user's url. For e.g,

```
private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL2 = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterusename";
```

How do i go on about making the request and retrieving the tweets associated to this account?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the lines of the [example](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample.java) that make the protected resource request with:

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json");
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
Response response = request.send();
System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
System.out.println();
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the library - saves me a lot of time !